# Repair windows 10 that halts on boot

Tags: windows-10, boot

Windows 10 boots and stops at boot screen: [see boots screen with options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GheJ8.png)

I do not have a bootable repair usb installation. So I tried with command line commands:

1. `chkdsk /f /x` find nothing to fix
2. `chkdsk /R` repairs something , but halted after about 50% with this message: `Unknown error (75736e6a726e6c2e 500)`
3. I wish to run the chkdsk after reboot, but apparently I can’t from this console
4. I tried `sfc /scannow` but it returns protection error and sfc doesn’t run.

Please help me with:

1. Is there any way to find the error message that broke windows? Any log file?
2. How can I run sfc from console opened from boot menu?
3. What else can I try?
4. If I create a bootable usb from another laptop, with windows 11, can it be useful?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The answer will likely depend on how recent your backup is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer at my question because I succeeded in fix part of the error and let Windows start, in which I had much more tools.

I did the following 2 steps:

1. `chkdsk /R`, as i said in the question, repairs something, and it could have helped someway
2. SFC worked when i run the command with the following parameters: `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c: /offwindir=c:\windows`

Note: both commands didn’t work at full capability, but it was enough to start Windows again.

Comment: If you have Windows 10 able to start then you can try a Windows 10 Repair Install to restore better functionality. I added this step to my answer

Comment: If this solved the issue accept as answer, even if it's your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Windows 10 Repair Steps ("Repair Installs") require that Windows 10 be running.

Your Windows 10 machine is not running.

So boot with a bootable (Windows) USB Key, recover your data to a USB drive.

You can try a Windows Reset (Update, Recovery, Reset), but that depends upon your Windows User Profile being good. It may be worth trying, but that is a grey area.

Otherwise format and reinstall Windows fresh is the final option.

**Follow up:**

If after some trial and error you are able to get Windows running,  then you should consider a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.  Try this first.

Comment: You mean no repair action is suitable? 
Is there any way to read some reason in any log file?

Comment: That is correct. No repair action is suitable on a machine that will not run.

Comment: But it opens in a blue bootable screen with a command line and tools. Are those not able to try any fix?

Comment: You can try a Windows Reset (Update, Recovery) and see it that works. That depends on your  Windows User Profile being good. Most often, if the Profile is good the system will start. So it is a very grey area here.

Comment: Thanks.
Does it reset all system? Or will it come back as yesterday before any error?

Comment: A reset will make you reinstall Apps.  It may be able to save Data (and may not) you have to try. It will NOT come back as yesterday before error.